# Convert String to Number. Must always be NaN if conversion fails

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following String to Number conversion, in Typescript, returns the results:

```
console.log(+'20'); > 20
console.log(+'A');  > NaN
console.log(+' ');  > 0
console.log(+'');   > 0
```

How to make sure that any string with invalid number returns NaN and not 0.

I would need the last two to return NaN not the default number value.

**Update**

Following some suggestion I tried:

```
console.log('20.35'.trim() == '' ? NaN : +('20.35'.trim()));    > 20.35

console.log('20'.trim() == '' ? NaN : +('20'.trim()));          > 20

console.log('-1.75 '.trim() == '' ? NaN : +('-1.75 '.trim()));  > -1.75

console.log(''.trim() == '' ? NaN : +(''.trim()));              > NaN

console.log('   '.trim() == '' ? NaN : +('   '.trim()));        > NaN
```

This works as expected. Not sure if it is the best option or if I am missing something out.

Comment: Trim the string and treat empty string separately?

Comment: I second that solution, I'd trim all the trailing space and remove all duplicated spacing, then treat the empty string

Comment: FWIW, the conversion does not "fail". The ES spec says that the number value of a string containing only white space characters or an empty string is `0`.

Comment: @Felix Kling I understand but I am sending this to an API as JSON and when the user inputs not value and I get an empty string I need to consider this as NaN / null and not as 0.

Comment: @FelixKling I updated my question with code that follows your trim suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parseInt(i)` or `parseFloat(i)`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
parseInt('10') === 10;
parseInt('A') === NaN;
parseInt(' ') === NaN;
parseInt('') === NaN;
parseFloat('10.20') === 10.2;
parseFloat('10') === 10;
```

Comment: That allows even more inputs to be turned into valid Numbers (e.g. `"123abc"`).

Comment: The number can also be a '20.35'. It is a Typescript number not necessary an int. if you try parseInt('20.75') you will get 30 and not 20.75.

Comment: Then use parseFloat. I edited the example. @FelixKling that could be a problem. A regex check could help. It depends on the usecase.

Comment: I do not know in advance what kind of number the string contains. So I cannot use parseInt or parseFloat.

Comment: @MiguelMoura can you provide an example that `parseFloat` isn't suitable for?

Comment: @HarryVane In fact it is suitable. I misinterpreted something on my code. I just accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
+'' == 0 ? NaN : 1   -> return NaN

+ ' ' ? NaN : 1       -> return 1
```

Comment: That is an option but what if the string is '       '?

Comment: As you can see in first one, When ' ' you will get NaN